# adding messagebox in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How would I add a javascript MessageBox in ASP.NET in the code behind pages using C#.

I have something like this in mind although I still cant get it quite right.

```
if (success == false)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert('User name already exists')</SCRIPT>");

    }
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below link will be helpful

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock.aspx

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/JavaScript_with_ASP_NET_2_0_Pages_Part1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478975.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
alert('hello world');
</script>
```

You can use the ASP.NET codebehind to write it to the page

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + myStringVariable + "');", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `HiddenField` to your ASPX

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="errorHf" />
```

Add the following JS code to your ASPX page

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var sErrorData = $('#errorHf').val();
        if (sErrorData != "") {
            alert(sErrorData);
            $('#errorHf').val("");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Once you get an error, just set `errorHf.Value`

```
if (!success)
    errorHf.Value = "Something went wrong!";
```

Don't forget to reset the error message on each `Page_Load`, so add

```
errorHf.Value = String.Empty;
```

So the message won't persist with each Postback.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
    Dim script As String =
     "<script language='javascript'>" &
     "alert('my message');" &
     "</script>"
    Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Me.Page.ClientScript
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(String), "myAlertID", script)
```